# How to cite the title AND the year in the same command?

Tags: biblatex, biber

I would like to cite an article by its title and its date (the date should be inside parenthesis).

For now, I have to use two commands:

```
\citetitle{key} \parencite*{key}
```

which produces (with authoryear style):

```
 My title (1999)
```

I am using Biblatex which has the same kind of command I want but for the name of author(s) and the date (`\textcite{key}` produces `Author (1999)`)

Is there a way to cite the title as a sentence's subject and the date in parenthesis by one biblatex command ? (I didn't anything related in bibaltex's manual)

Comment: I'm not to fluent in biblatex, but you could change the cite style. However, why not go the direct route \newcommand{\mycite}[1]{\citetitle{#1} \parencite*{#1}}

Comment: @bort Because it's appears like I cited twice the paper. It could generate problem if I use specific biblatex features to see how frequently I cite some reference.

Comment: Define a new  cite command `\citetitleyear`. The documentation says how to do it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT** Improved code thanks to moewe's help.

Possibly something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples}
\DeclareCiteCommand{\citetitleyear}
{\boolfalse{citetracker}%
  \boolfalse{pagetracker}}
{\ifciteindex
  {\indexfield{indextitle}}
  {}%
  \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \printtext[parens]{%
    \usebibmacro{prenote}%
    \printfield{year}\printfield{extrayear}%
    \usebibmacro{postnote}}}
{\multicitedelim}
{}
\begin{document}

  \citetitleyear{westfahl:space}

  \citetitleyear{westfahl:space,matuz:doody}

  \citetitleyear[pre][3--9]{westfahl:space}

\end{document}
```

[image: cite title and year]

Comment: +1) It is probably a bit more idiomatic to use `\printtext[parens]` instead of `\mkbibparens`. Then you can use `\setunit{\addspace}` instead of the bare `\addspace`. In combination that should have exactly the same result, but it feels a bit more `biblatex`-y.

Comment: @moewe Thanks. I will update this shortly. Is `\mkbibparens` really for use in documents as opposed to formatting commands?

Comment: As far as I can tell `\mkbibparens` and friends are really only ever used in `\DeclareFieldFormat` directives. If you want to have parentheses and such in your `biblatex` macros, the way to go seems to be  `\printtext[parens]`. But this is more or less from what I observed so far, the only official thing I could find is §4.11.7 *Using the Punctuation Tracker* in the docs, esp. §4.11.7.2. It is quite easy to come up with code that uses `\mkbibparens` and shows side effects, some of them can be avoided at the cost of other undesirables.

Comment: @moewe Thanks! Could you check I've got it right?