# Numeric Citation Style with Footnotes

Tags: biblatex, citing, footnotes

friends,

I'm currently writing my bachelors thesis. I used the numeric style citations and they worked fine until my professor decided he wanted footnotes with author, title and pages as well as citation numbers in superscript.

So basically the numeric-comp citation and bibliography style with supercite, BUT also footnotes.

It should look something like this (This is not generated with latex, just an example):

[image]

If possible, I would like to add the page numbers as plain text manually for each citation, so the p. and pp. aren't automated. For different sources (like web pages) I would also like author and title with a manual note like above with page numbers. Ideally each source only shows up once per page but at this point I would be happy if the citations worked at all.

My Setup is:

```
\documentclass[twoside,10pt, ngerman, numbers=noenddot, headsepline]{scrreprt} 
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric-comp, sorting=none]{biblatex}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, bookmarks, bookmarksnumbered, bookmarksopen, bookmarksopenlevel=1, linkcolor=black, citecolor=black, urlcolor=blue, filecolor=blue,  pdfpagelayout=OneColumn, pdfnewwindow=true, pdfstartview=XYZ, plainpages=false, pdfpagelabels},
]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\printbibliography[title=Literaturverzeichnis]

\end{document}
```

I spent a few hours searching for the right solutions, trying to implement other solutions and customise my citation styles but I'm not a good programmer and english isn't my first language so I just can't get there. I really hope someone is able to help me.

I can post a code example, but I'm not sure if it would help, since I'm using the standard numeric-comp citation style without any modifications.

Thank you all so much!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Could you edit in some code please so we can see what your setup is?

Comment: Things like https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35673/35864 exist, but they are pretty difficult to pull off properly. Is there any chance you can get your professor to relent and accept a more sane citation style? (Maybe check a few journals in your area of research and show your professor that they use a different style.)

Comment: Suppose (as in your example) you cite source 3 several times on one page, but that (additionally) each time the page range is different. How would that be reflected accurately in the footnote?

Comment: how is the ordering in the footnotes? Why is it "1,3" in the first line?

Comment: @moewe: I added my setup, I hope this is enough!

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Yes, you're right, that doesn't make sense. The numering is the order in which they appear in the document.

Comment: I wasn't to fussed about the setup, as I thought the description reasonably clear. But still, thanks for the code example. You may want to remove your name and document title from the `hyperref` options though. (Check the capitalisation of `inhalationssystems`.) I did have a few other questions in my comments though.

Comment: Here is another one: What is supposed to happen if you cite work A, B on page 1 and then on page 2 you cite work C and then afterwards work A again (in this example A would become 1, B 2 and C 3). Do you want the footnote of A (1) to appear before that of C (3) even though on that page the order is different?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/71526/35864 might be a better alternative to https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35673/35864 I linked above.

Comment: @moewe: I will talk to my professor, but I'm not sure he will change his mind. The order of the citations can be the same in wich they appear in the text, no need to sort them from low to high.

Comment: but should the same citation always have the same number or can they change? And if they can change is the bibliography sorted by author and title so that the reader can find entries?

Comment: The Citation should alsways have the same number. So like the numeric style but with the numbers in supercript (just like \supercite) instead of brackets.

Comment: sorry but this is mad. How on earth should a reader find a reference if the footnotes go `10 Author A` , `91 Author B` , `22 Author C`? on a page? (And I hope that you don't have real footnotes, as this would give a complete mess, superscript doesn't go well with footnotes anyway).

Comment: I completely agree with Ulrike. At this point the style does not appear to be thought through properly. While it may appear to be acceptable not to sort the citations in the footnotes by their label if there are only two or three citations, this will get confusing if there are more. ...

Comment: ... I think such a setup only makes sense if you treat the citation footnotes at the bottom as a sort of "mini bibliography" of all the sources you cited on that page. This "mini bibliography" would ideally be independent of "normal footnotes" in your document and it would be sorted just like the real bibliography at the end by the numeric citation labels. I don't think I have ever seen something like this in the real world, though. Plus it would have trouble dealing with different page ranges for cites (the subject of my second comment above: how do you want to deal with that).

Comment: I think the intention is, that he doesn't want to have to jump to the bibliography every time he checks the citation (I'm guessing that's also why he wants the page numbers, so he can check easily). The most citations I have on a page are about 5, so I don't think it would get too crowded. I'll talk to my professor again tough and tell him it won't work that way.

Comment: The different page ranges is why I would want to add a sort of note manually. I'd just type out the pages for each entry

Comment: Sure that is sort of possible if the rest is implemented. The question is what you do if you cite the same source twice on the same page. How do you indicate which page reference belongs where?

Comment: If your professor has an easier time remembering author and years instead of numbers (I totally get that), why don't you just use an author-year citation scheme (as in `\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear,]{biblatex}` with `\autocite[380-382]{sigfridsson}` you can directly refer to the relevant pages)?

Comment: I think I will go with that, thanks. I just really like the numeric citations, but he's the one evaluating me ;) Would it be possible to show author, year and title?

Comment: Author-year citations are actually very common in many fields. But I guess many people are used to the look of numeric citations thanks to Wikipedia. Yes, it is possible to show author, title and year. But that is not a standard style. I am not aware of a "serious publication" actively using such a style. Plus, it is (mostly) redundant. There are implementation of such a style on this site, but I always have a hard time finding them. I'll have a look.

Comment: I managed to find https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/215512/35864 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/123104/35864 (do not use the accepted answer in the second link! instead go for https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/123145/35864.) Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/284207/35864.